# How to change a "hidden variable" to NULL whenever page is reloaded

Tags: oracle-apex

Please explain how to change a "hidden variable", say `p_show_variable`, to NULL whenever page is reloaded.

I have a conditional report in a page , and the requirement is whenever any variable changes and that "Submits" the page , then `p_show_variable` should become NULL, thus hiding the conditional report.

Answer (score 0):

Create unconditional PL/SQL proccess on your Page Rendering. Add some code:

```
BEGIN
  :P_SHOW_VARIABLE := NULL;
END;
```

You can also add some condition on proccess, for example, Request=Expression. Change button action to Redirect and set Request value. Use this value as Expression in process condition. 
Or set condition for proccess When Button pressed and set button name.